# Account lockout setting in Centos 6

Tags: centos, pam

I'm trying to implement an account lockout after 3 fail sign-on attempt. Root is exempted.

Here's what I have in my **/etc/pam.d/system-auth** file so far

```
auth        required      pam_tally2.so deny=3 onerr=fail magic_root
account     required      pam_tally2.so
```

On my **/etc/pam.d/sshd** file, I have added the following line

```
auth        required      pam_tally2.so deny=3 onerr=fail magic_root
```

However this does not work. I have tried logging in via SSH with a test non-root user and wrong password but it does not lock me out.

However, if I tweak the **/etc/pam.d/sshd** file and remove the magic_root line, like so:

```
auth        required      pam_tally2.so deny=3 onerr=fail
```

The test account will lock out.

Am I missing something out there?

Also, could someone please explain the difference between **/etc/pam.d/system-auth** and **/etc/pam.d/password-auth**? Should settings like these goes into system-auth or password-auth? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have personal experience, but I think you may be misreading the man page for `pam_tally2`.

Mine says

> magic_root
>
> If the module is invoked by a user with uid=0 the counter
>   is not incremented. The  sysadmin should use this for user launched
>   services, like su, otherwise this argument  should be omitted.

Note the comment about only using with `su`.  Why?  Because most other times, this module is `always` invoked by a user with EUID 0, as most system services that will use this module (`passwd`, `sshd`, etc.) run as root, as indeed they must.

So what flag do you need to set to avoid root being locked out by this module under eg `sshd`?  The man page also states that:

> Normally, failed attempts to access root will not cause the root account to become blocked, to
>   prevent denial-of-service: if your users aren´t given shell accounts and root may only login via
>   su or at the machine console (not telnet/rsh, etc), this is safe.

In other words, the behaviour you want is already the default.